# jquery animation effect after a certain interval of time

Tags: jquery

I want div animation effect.
For eg:-  I have two divs, `div A, div B`
`Div A` appears with text `abc` on the left of the page and fades in after 10seconds and then on right side of page `Div B` appears with text `ghi` and fades after 10seconds and again left side div appears and so on.... 
Can anyone help, how to proceed with the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the jQuery Website: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Here is a basic example:

```
function animateDivs1() {
    $('div#divOne').delay(800).fadeIn(400);
    $('div#divTwo').delay(800).fadeOut(400);
    animateDivs2();
}

function animateDivs2() {
    $('div#divOne').delay(800).fadeOut(400);
    $('div#divTwo').delay(800).fadeIn(400);
    animateDivs1();
}

animateDivs1();
```

​
Also you can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/hPNjn/

Comment: Thanx, In this, i want that when first div appears, it should be visible for 10sec and then slowly vanish and then after first div vanishes, then second div appears and i want it to cycle not just stop after first move.

Comment: also, i want to appear automatically when the page loads , not on click

Comment: I've updated my answer with a basic example.